# CAN FD support for Virtual CAN (vcan) on SocketCAN

Tags: linux, can-bus, socketcan, canutils

I have been using SocketCAN and especially the Virtual CAN vcan for quite a while now. However, I never used CAN FD (Flexible Datarate) so far.

Well, I tried it this morning using the can-utils:

```
cansend vcan0 123##122
```

However, I got the response "CAN interface is not CAN FD capable".
The vcan interface has been created using the following terminal commands:

```
ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
ip link set up vcan0
```

Does anybody know if vcan supports CAN FD?
If yes, how do I set up a vcan interface supporting CAN FD?

System configuration: Ubuntu 14.04.1 on VirtualBox.

Thanks in advance,
MAW

Answer (score 8):

a colleague of mine found a solution:

```
ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
ip link set vcan0 mtu 72
```

The option "mtu 72" sets the right maximum transmission size for CAN FD. After that vcan accepts CAN FD messages.

MAW

Comment: "ip link set can0 mtu 72" returns, "RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument" did you do anything different to change the mtu?

Answer (score 3):

Excellent finding, MAW!

It works as a charm. Here is what I did, following your advice. Please, do note that commands are generic, and that there is a environment preparation I do NOT want to go into!

To set socketCAN framework beneath Linux kernel (I am using 4.17.2), please, as root:

```
lsmod | grep can
modprobe can
modprobe can_raw
modprobe can-bcm
modprobe can-dev
modprobe can-gw
modprobe vcan
lsmod | grep can
```

To set the socketCAN-Fd framework, the following should be done (also as root):

```
ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
ip link set vcan0 mtu 72
ip link set dev vcan0 up
ifconfig
```

The can-utils package is required to test the socketCAN-Fd framework. Also, the following is required:
https://github.com/mguentner/cannelloni

And, everything is working like Swiss Clock! :-)

On the xmit side: cangen -f vcan0 -v
vcan0

> 2C3##0.25.5A.FF.1E.DC.BD.CB.42.25.5A.FF.1E.DC.BD.CB.42.25.5A.FF.1E.DC.BD.CB.42.25.5A.FF.1E.DC.BD.CB.42.25.5A.FF.1E.DC.BD.CB.42.25.5A.FF.1E.DC.BD.CB.42.25.5A.FF.1E.DC.BD.CB.42.25.5A.FF.1E.DC.BD.CB.42

On the receiving side: candump vcan0

> vcan0  2C3  [64]  25 5A FF 1E DC BD CB 42 25 5A FF 1E DC BD CB 42 25
>   5A FF 1E DC BD CB 42 25 5A FF 1E DC BD CB 42 25 5A FF 1E DC BD CB 42
>   25 5A FF 1E DC BD CB 42 25 5A FF 1E DC BD CB 42 25 5A FF 1E DC BD CB
>   42

Perfect! Thank you so much!

*nobody*